# ImportError: cannot import name 'fromshare' from 'socket'

Tags: python, django, heroku

`im facing this error ImportError: cannot import name 'fromshare' from 'socket' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/socket.py) File "/app/coreapp/forms.py", line 1, in <module>from socket import fromshare`

````
` im facing this error ImportError: cannot import name 'fromshare' from 'socket' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/socket.py) File "/app/coreapp/forms.py", line 1, in <module>from socket import fromshare`
#i was trying to run Heroku run python manage.py migrate 
#my forms file :
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from coreapp.models import Restaurant
from django.db import models

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
  email = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
  
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", "password", "first_name", "last_name", "email")

class RestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Restaurant
    fields = ("name", "phone", "address", "logo")  ```
`
 File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/foodhub/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from coreapp import views
  File "/app/coreapp/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from coreapp.forms import UserForm,RestaurantForm
  File "/app/coreapp/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from socket import fromshare
ImportError: cannot import name 'fromshare' from 'socket' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/socket.py)`
````

Comment: [`socket.fromshare` only exists on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.fromshare). Did you try to ship an entire virtual environment to Herkou? Or maybe you're using a Windows-only dependency? Please add the full error tracback instead of just that one line.

Comment: i have add the full trace error

Comment: but i already delete this module from forms and still facing same error

Comment: How did you remove it? According to the error message you still have `from socket import fromshare` on line 1 of your `coreapp/forms.py` file. You need to remove it locally, commit that change, and redeploy.

Comment: now its working thanks i just redploy and run and it works fine